# Draw handler for python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python program that I built for a school project.  It was done using a custom gui module they created to work in web browser.  I wanted to port the program to something I can use in the real world.  I rebuilt it using tkinter.  The module they used had a draw handler that just redrew the canvas 60 times per second.  I was not sure how to handle that so I did the following.  It works but the program becomes unresponsive after a few minutes.  Is there a better way to handle this?  Thanks.

```
def draw(self):
    label1 = ttk.Label(self, text=message1)
    label1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    horizontal_position = 0
    current_card = 0
    for card in main_card_list:
        if exposed[current_card] == True:
            self.canvas.create_text(horizontal_position + 25, 50, text=str(card), font=("Purisa",30))
            self.canvas.grid()
        if exposed[current_card] == False:
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(current_card * 50, 0, (current_card + 1) * 50, 100, outline="#f11", fill="#1f1", width=2)
            self.canvas.grid()
        horizontal_position += 50
        current_card += 1
    self.after(100, self.draw)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is freezing because there are too many canvas items; you should clear the canvas every once in a while using `canvas.delete(ALL)`.

Comment: Excellent!, I put that in the beginning of my draw method and it works perfect.  Thank You.